# Jacobian of Stabilized Eikonal Equation $| \nabla u| = 1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, finite-element-method

I am trying to implement a Finite Element Solution for the Stabilized Eikonal Equation :

$$ |\nabla u| = 1 + \Gamma \Delta u, \quad \text{ where } \quad u = \text{ distance function }$$

$$ \text{such that } \quad u_{\partial \Omega} = 0  \quad \text{ and }\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \bigg|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$$ and
$$ \Gamma = \text{Some Parameter Depending on the mesh or problem definition}$$

With, $ v = \text{Test Function and } u = \text{Trial Function}$, the weak-form of the equation can be written as:

$\int_\Omega \left( v|\nabla u| \right)dx = \int_\Omega \left[ vdx + v(\Gamma \Delta u )dx \right] $

Integrating by parts and applying boundary conditions:

$$\int_\Omega \left( v|\nabla u| \right)dx = \int_\Omega \left[ vdx - \Gamma (\nabla u \cdot \nabla v)dx \right] $$

$$ F(u; v) = \int_\Omega \left( v|\nabla u| \right)dx - vdx + \Gamma (\nabla u \cdot \nabla v)dx $$

$F(u; v)$ is a Nonlinear function of u. And as a result, I am trying to employ the Newton's(Newton-Rhapson method) for the solving the above non-linear problem.

Considering the example as shown in the section [Solving the Nonlinear Variational Problem Directly](http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/nonlinear.html), the Gateaux derivative $DF(u^k; \delta u, v)$ of $F(u;v)$ at $ u = u\_ $ in the direction of $\delta u$ can be written as:

$$ \begin{align*} J = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{d\over d\epsilon} F_i(u_{-} + \epsilon\delta u; v) & = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{d\over d\epsilon} \left \{ \int_\Omega \left( v|\nabla (u_{-} + \epsilon \delta u)| \right)dx - vdx + \Gamma \nabla (u_{-} + \epsilon \delta u) \cdot \nabla v)dx \right \} \\ 
& =  \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_\Omega \frac{v \nabla (u_{-} + \epsilon \delta u)}{|\nabla (u_{-} + \epsilon \delta u)|} \cdot \nabla \delta u dx  - 0 + \Gamma \nabla \delta u \cdot \nabla v dx \\ 
& = \int_\Omega \frac{v \nabla \delta u \cdot \nabla u_{-} }{|\nabla u_{-}|} + \Gamma \nabla \delta u \cdot \nabla v \end{align*}  $$

Hence, forming $$ [ J ] \delta u = -F(u_{-}; v) \quad \text{where, } u_{-} = \text{Initial Solution for iteration} \\ \text{Next iteration Value is given by } = u_{-} + \omega \delta u \quad \forall \omega \in (0, 1] $$

Clearly, the Jacobian from the above format consist of Nonlinear terms. I have tried multiple ways to compute the expression and have no idea if I am right  !!!! .

Can anyone please give me a hint, as, how to calculate the expression for the jacobian of $F(u; v)$ ??

Comment: Are you certain about the boundary conditions? I'm a bit confused with both Dirichlet and Neumann conditions for a second order PDE.

Comment: I am referring to [Differential equation-based wall distance computation for DES and RANS](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021999103002729/1-s2.0-S0021999103002729-main.pdf?_tid=581af772-3697-11e5-9e88-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1438246115_be8e9899ab96132d1c4c4a488a272f02). Please see *section 2.7 Boundary Conditions*

Comment: So there are some Neumann and some Dirichlet conditions on some parts of the boundary, but not both. From that work, I also suspect that FEM might not be a good choice for an eikonal equation. You can try, and your Jacobian looks ok, but you method might work very strangely, advancing front a bit on every iteration. Also, there's no upwinding in this method, so hyperbolic nature of the equation will manifest itself in oscillations.

Comment: One more thing, note that Jacobian has $|\nabla u_{-}|$ in the denominator and that is a problem. That means you need a good starting solution, definitely not a constant. To get round the problem you may try substituting $|\nabla u_{-}| \to 1$ for the Jacobian, that would make no difference when close to the solution and may resolve issues with starting point. Though, that would break Newton's method, so no fast convergence. But the convergence may be the issue even without that kind of regularization